# Integer model attribute gets converted to string in assert_equal call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When I am checking the value of an integer model attribute with assert_equal, the value returned is a string.

I am running an integration test where I update a model instance and then check the model instance to insure the values has been changed.

database table:

```
create_table :launches do |t|
  ...
  t.integer :result
  ...

  t.timestamps
end
```

model:

```
validates :result, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
```

Here is the test:

```
@launch.reload
assert_equal 2, @launch.result
```

and it produces this error:

```
test_edit_a_launch#LaunchesNewAndEditTest (0.99s)
    Expected: 2
      Actual: "2"
    test/integration/launches_new_and_edit_test.rb:57:in `block in <class:LaunchesNewAndEditTest>'
```

The values is getting returned as a string and the comparison to an integer fails.  If I change the test to:

```
@launch.reload
assert_equal 2, @launch.result.to_i
```

it works.  But this does not make any sense and it should be comparing an integer value in the model to the integer expected result.  When I manipulate the object in rails console, the value is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the test database and the development database (both PostgreSQL) got out of sync.  The 'result' column originally was 'character variable'.  In the course of development, I changed it to an integer column in a migration and ran it.  For some reason, the migration did not run on the test database.

To fix it, I ran the following command:

```
rails db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```